# Ansible parsing a JSON Object

Tags: python, json, api, split, ansible

I have a Problem with parsing a JSON Object. I get the JSON Object from uri. I need the number 13 in the string for the next task. Does anybody know, how it is possible to get only the number from this JSON Object?

```
 - name: GET JOB INFORMATION
    uri:
      url: "http://******"
      method: GET
      headers:
        Accept: 'application/json'
        Content-Type: 'application/json'
        Authorization: 'Session {{ xxx.json.token }}'
    register: result_job
  
 - name: Output_1
   debug:
     msg: "{{ result_job.json.affectedResources }}"

  - name: Output_2
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result_job.json.affectedResources.split('/')[0] | last }}"
```

When ansible execute the Task "Output_2" i got an Error:

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'split'\n\nThe error appears to have been in
```

The Output of the Task "Output_1" is this:

```
    "msg": [
        "/Manager/tes/objects/bew/13"
    ]
```

And the JSON Object look like this:

```
    "msg": {
       "affectedResources": [
        "/Manager/tes/objects/bew/13"
    ],
    "completedTime": "2022-03-16T..."
    "createdTime": "2022...."
   }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data

```yaml
  result_job:
    json:
      affectedResources:
      - /Manager/tes/objects/bew/13
      completedTime: 2022-03-16T...
      createdTime: 2022....
```

You can see the attribute *affectedResources* is a list. You say that you *`"need the number 13 in the string"`*. In this case, let's take the first element from the list

```yaml
"{{ result_job.json.affectedResources.0 }}"
```

gives the string

```yaml
/Manager/tes/objects/bew/13
```

Now, you can split the string and get the last item either by index

```yaml
"{{ result_job.json.affectedResources.0.split('/').[-1] }}"
```

, or by the filter

```yaml
"{{ result_job.json.affectedResources.0.split('/')|last }}"
```

Both give the same result

```yaml
'13'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that works as long as two conditions are true:

1. In the string ("/Manager/tes/objects/bew/13" in your case), there is *only one* number enclosed in '/'.
2. The number enclosed in '/' (for example, '/13/') is an integer.

Your JSON Object (called `json_object` in the script):

```json
"msg": {
       "affectedResources": [
        "/Manager/tes/objects/bew/13"
    ],
    "completedTime": "2022-03-16T..."
    "createdTime": "2022...."
}
```

Here's the script.

```py
# Navigate to the appropriate element in the JSON object
string = json_object["msg"]["affectedResources"][0]
for item in string.split('/'): # iterate on items between '/'
    try:
        return_val = int(item) # if the item is an integer
        break # quit and keep that value
    except:
        return_val = None # or other default value
        continue

# Result
print(return_val, type(return_val)) >>> 13, <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for your response. Is that a Python script? I need it for ansible.

Comment: @afschir Yes, it's Python.